# Databinding block generating only ampersands

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to generate a number of characters (in this case stars) in a databinding block.  All it is generating on the client side is ampersands (the correct number though).

```
<span class="review-stars">
    <%# New String("&#9733;", Eval("CustomerReviewScore"))%>
</span>
```

I am not sure what I need to do for the characters to actually come up on the client.

EDIT:

HTML is:

```
<span class="review-stars">&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;</span>
```

Comment: When you view source on the client side, what is getting rendered?

Comment: @AnnL. add the HTML to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Literal`](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/use-aspnets-literal-control-to-its-full-potential/618) control instead and set it's [`Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) property to `PassThrough`:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1"
    Mode="PassThrough"
    Text= '<%# New String("&#9733;", Eval("CustomerReviewScore"))%>'       
    runat="server">
</asp:Literal>
```

Comment: That worked quite nicely.  I'll hold off marking this as the answer for a little bit in case there is a more elegant solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @StefanH: Btw, you can add anything to the text property of a `Literal` control. Even your span + css-class.